# QGIS: georeference a jpeg map working on avenza maps app

Tags: qgis, georeferencing, maps, avenza

I am trying to georeference a map on QGIS. I used this video to teach me how to do it, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jKLBFddpTGI. I found it fairly easy to do. I do use WGS84, that was the first thing I checked.

I am trying to reference a map of South Africa. Once I have made the map and imported it into the Avenza app it is not georeferenced properly and the map is somewhere in the middle of the ocean.

I am m not sure what else I can do to rectify the georeferencing. Any assistance would be great.

Comment: Please post your original map, your geo-referenced map, and a screenshot of the dislocation in Avenza.